# Xpages - How to display richtext field image properties on an Xpage?

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages, lotus-domino

I have a notes form with a richtext field in which I 'embed' inline images through Create > Picture. The images are displayed correctly, but no properties are getting displayed. For example, I set caption or title, nothing is shown on the Xpage when previewed.
Are this properties supported in Xpages or there is some kind of way to display them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These properties are not supported. In genral: RichText doesn't map very well to HTML/MIME, so you will always run into limitations. You could check out Geniisoft's iFidelity which does enhanced rt-mime conversion. Unless you work on a conversion of a clasic app it is better to work with mime only instead of RT

Comment: I'm trying to build a new app, but I'm learning as I go, that's why I ask maybe too many questions here :) Which BTW I appreciate all the answers you guys give me here...
Anyways, how can I work with mime only?

Comment: Asking questions is the way to learn, so go ahead. Suggest you make "How to store MIME only" a new question. The short answer: it is a property in the RT Field. There are other ways too.